# PreferenceFragmentCompat is not taking the correct androidx PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, preference, preferencefragment

I am trying to create a preference screen using `androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0`, however, when I create the settings xml file following this guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html, it is taking the platform `Preferences`.

As it is taking `android.preference`, I can't use 'SeekBarPreferece`which is only in`androidx`, that's why it shows a warning.

[image]

I can change the package name to fit `androidx` ones. However, now it doesn't find it and can check the reference (it finds `PreferenceScreen` and `PreferenceCategory` but no `SeekBarPreference` which is in the same package.

[image]
[image]

Has it happenened to any of you ? Here is the code:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey)
    }

}

<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        app:title="@string/settings_notifications">

        <SwitchPreference
            app:key="notifications"
            app:title="@string/settings_news"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon_news"
            android:summaryOff="@string/settings_news_off"
            android:summaryOn="@string/settings_news_on"/>

        <SeekBarPreference
            app:key="feedback"
            app:title="@string/settings_aviso_level"
            android:max="5"
            android:defaultValue="5"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"

            />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Edit:**
I was having this issue in Android Studio 3.4 and it is fixed in 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Android Studio are you using? This has been fixed in 3.5, so if you are using the latest releases it should work.

In any case, this is just a warning that studio displays - it doesn't mean that it is using `android.preference.*` classes. If you are using the xml file from within `androidx.preference.*`, i.e using a `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, then it will correctly use the `androidx` classes - so it should work fine, and you can just ignore this until you update your Android Studio.

You can either just use the class name, like `SeekBarPreference`, or the fully qualified name, `androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference` and both should work when building and running the app.